# How to sum a column of a Db

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sum

Sorry I'm a newbie in Java. I want to fetch all notes(KEY_Time), sum them and return the sum as a string.  When I want to execute a statement like the folowing one, my app crashes.

```
String rawQuery = 
    "SELECT _id, fehlzeiten, 
         SUM(fehlzeiten) as sum 
         FROM notes";
     sqliteCallLogsDB.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
```

### NotesDbAdapter :

```
public class NotesDbAdapter {

public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_Test = "test";
public static final String KEY_Time = "fehlzeiten";
private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

/**
 * Database creation sql statement
 */

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "title text not null, body text not null, fehlzeiten text not null, test text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
 * opened/created
 * 
 * @param ctx the Context within which to work
 */
public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {

    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

/**
 * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
 * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
 * signal the failure
 * 
 * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
 *         initialization call)
 * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
 */
public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {

    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}


/**
 * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
 * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
 * a -1 to indicate failure.
 * 
 * @param title the title of the note
 * @param body the body of the note
 * @return rowId or -1 if failed
 */
public long createNote(String title, String body, String fehlzeit, String test) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    initialValues.put(KEY_Time, fehlzeit);
    initialValues.put(KEY_Test, test);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

/**
 * Delete the note with the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to delete
 * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
 */
public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
 * 
 * @return Cursor over all notes
 */
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_Time,KEY_Test}, null, null, null, null, null);
}




/**
 * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
 * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
 * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
 */
public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY,KEY_Time,KEY_Test}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}


/**
 * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
 * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
 * values passed in
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to update
 * @param title value to set note title to
 * @param body value to set note body to
 * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
 */
public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String body, String fehlzeiten, String test) {

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    args.put(KEY_Time, fehlzeiten);
    args.put(KEY_Test, test);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Anytime you're asking for help here and it's about an app crash, it's almost always helpful to post the stack trace as well. This gives us more information about the actual problem so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand properly you store your Fehlzeiten as String. Thats not very convenient. Switch it to INTEGER and get a sum like this:

```
public long getFehlzeitenSum() {
    long result = 0;
    Cursor c = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
      new String[] { "sum(" + KEY_Time + ")" },
      null, 
      null, 
      null /* you may add a GROUP BY attribute (e.g. KEY_Test) here */,
      null /* and here a HAVING for your group-by-clause */, 
      null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        result = c.getLong(0);
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```

As *tuze* pointed out you can't mix aggregation-functions with regular values (Except for those which stand in GROUP BY).

Answer (score 1):

SUM() returns only one row without GROUP BY clause. So, you can't fetch regular column data with it.

```
SELECT SUM(fehlzeiten) as sum FROM notes
```

Comment: also i must wirte : SELECT SUM(fehlzeiten) as sum From notes GROUP BY test ?

Comment: That query just fetchs the sum of fehlzeiten column. You need an other query to fetch the values you need. Like, `SELECT _id, fehlzeiten FROM notes`

Comment: Sorry but i'm clueless about this all. I must write a app for my school but they didn't teach me to write in java. im must write it in 5 weeks for them. it's not posible to lear so much in this short time :D is it posible that you can give me a example that i return the sum of all values of fehlzeiten. Sorry that i ask a lot.

Comment: Your fehlzeiten column's data type is TEXT. You can't use SUM function on that. Turn it into INT. Try @Omphaloskopie's solution.